# Insert controls Use in Database

Tags: controls

I am using visual studio 2003 and i have big application. I want to do the user rights management in my application.I have created database in which i want to enter the forms name,Controls name and menu names. how i can get the list of controls which i put on the 
form ?

example: i put text box and two button on the one form then i want the list of that text box and two button in list ?
Mainly i want button list use in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly. I guess it is like a user with XYZ role should be able to click the button while one with ABC cannot.

If I am correct, then this is not the way you implement it. What you can do is:

1. Have user roles defined and assign them rights in the database.
2. Assign each user to a role.
3. In your application, check for the role and enable disable controls accordingly.

If this is not what you are asking please rephrase.

Comment: Yes you are right i want like that i want to enable and disable the controls  on the basis of the database i have problem i have very big system i want to enter the all the button with form which use in the system so that is  my question i don't want do manually because it will take very much time so any process from that i put entry in the database for all the buttons.